How to Stabilize Decal Placement on Mesh in React Three Fiber?
I'm facing an issue with decal placement on a mesh surface in React Three Fiber. As I decrease the decal's scale, it gradually penetrates the mesh until it disappears completely. I temporarily fixed this by adjusting the Z-index in the position attribute, but this won't work once I start dynamically scaling and positioning the decal.
How can I ensure the decal remains on the surface of the mesh at all scales and positions? I'm relatively new to React Three Fiber, so any tips or alternative methods would be appreciated!
return (
  <>
    <OrbitControls
      ref={controls}
      rotateSpeed={0.5}
      enablePan={false}
      autoRotate={rotateEnabled} 
      autoRotateSpeed={0.5} 
      maxPolarAngle={Math.PI / 2}
      minPolarAngle={Math.PI / 2.5}
    />
    <ambientLight intensity={0.5} />
    <directionalLight position={[5, 5, 5]} intensity={0.8} castShadow />
    <directionalLight position={[-5, -5, -5]} intensity={0.5} />
    <group key={stateString} ref={meshRef}>
      {Object.values(nodes).map((mesh, index) => (
        <mesh
          key={index}
          geometry={mesh.geometry}
          material={mesh.material}
          visible={mesh.visible}
          dispose={null}
          castShadow
          receiveShadow
        >
          {mesh.name === "Pattern2D_96990" && (
            <>
              <Decal
                position={[0, 1.36707867752322905, 0]}
                rotation={[0, 0, 0]}
                scale={0.25}
                map={logoTexture}
                map-anisotropy={16}
                depthTest={false}
                depthWrite={true}
              />
            </>
          )}
        </mesh>
      ))}
    </group>
  </>
);

Thank you in advance for your help!
